# Jdeveloper Sql Server Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to connect sqlserver on Jdeveloper. I installed the suggested jar file to followed the steps on link pointed below.

http://souviksoa.blogspot.com.tr/2013/07/setup-sqlservers-connection-in.html

However, i'm writing connection information and after click test connection button, it gives the following error.

[error_message visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcvBt.jpg)

Firewall is closed on my computer, i don't have  antivirus program, and ***i can connect the database with different IDE's such as Visual Studio.***

What could be the problem, do you have any ideas? My operating system is windows 8.1

thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you enter a "Custom JDBC URL"?

Comment: Nothing is changed. It gave me same error

Comment: Are you using JDBC when you connect from Visual Studio - if not then it probably is not an indicator that your server is setup correctly to be connected on this port.

Comment: I don't use JDBC but 1433 isn't it the default port for sqlserver? Is it relevant with JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

If your sql server is default instance you have to clear instance  name box.

For example if you are using localhost  or "." to connect to sql server in visual studio.